# Externally Accessible FTP Endpoint in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, aws-api-gateway

We have a 3rd party that we need a daily csv file from.  The only protocol they can use is FTP authenticated by username and password.  Is it possible to enable an FTP endpoint within AWS that a completely external user can drop files into?

We tried following the instructions and set up a stack and got the invoke URL, but the server it created is SFTP.  When trying to create an FTP server, if we choose publicly accessible it says:

"To use a Public endpoint type, disable FTPS and FTP in step 1"

If we choose VPC Hosted it says:

"Your server's endpoint can be hosted within your VPC only (for internal access only). To use a Internet Facing VPC endpoint type, disable FTP in step 1".

Is it possible to set up an externally accessible FTP endpoint in AWS?

These are the references we are using:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/create-server-ftp.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-ftp-and-ftps-in-addition-to-existing-sftp/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/authenticating-users.html#authentication-custom-ip

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I moved it, where it was promptly closed for being "Off-Topic".

Comment: OK, sorry for that. I believed it would be on-topic there. It's definitely not on-topic here.

Comment: Well if someone with your experience isn't sure where this belongs I don't have a snowball's chance in hell.  I'll find another venue to seek assistance.

Comment: Have You found any solution for this?